# PlayFramework - FakeRequest to upload file

Tags: scala, playframework

I am trying to test a controller to upload files. The controller receives a multipartform request.

In the test I am creating a FakeRequest this way

```
val tempFile = play.api.libs.Files.SingletonTemporaryFileCreator.create("prefix", "txt")

val file = FilePart("upload", "hello.txt", Option("text/plain"), tempFile)

val controller = new LoadController(controllerComponents)

val formData = MultipartFormData(
    dataParts = Map(),
    files = Seq(file),
    badParts = Seq())
val response = controller.upload.apply(FakeRequest(POST, "/upload").
    withHeaders(HeaderNames.CONTENT_TYPE -> "multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------968e587c4173725c").
    withMultipartFormDataBody(formData))
```

The controller receives the file to upload in the `upload` key. If I test the controller with curl, postman or another rest client it works, but in the test I am getting always the message `[Unexpected end of input]` as if the `upload` key was empty.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try removing the headers ? in the play [tests](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/c038bc147b03285a1de7acc50037e1e7f438bedf/documentation/manual/working/scalaGuide/main/upload/code/ScalaFileUpload.scala#L62) they don't set them

Comment: could it be that this `tempFile` is empty and that is the problem?

Comment: It appears the 'upload' key is empty for some reason

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same issue and found out that you need to set the `dataParts` property of `MultipartFormData`:

```
val formData = MultipartFormData(
  dataParts = Map("" -> Seq("dummydata")), 
  files =  Seq(file),
  badParts = Seq())
```

This way I also didn't have to set the content-type/boundary header.